# Calling a function when dropdown toggle is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, toggle

I have this dropdown-toggle and I want to call the function `read();` every time it is clicked or toggled. There is something wrong with the `onclick` command wherein it is always calling the function `read();` even though the toggle is not clicked. I have also tried other commands such as `ondrop`

Html:

```
        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="read();">
            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
            <span class="badge">
                <%=unread%>
            </span>
        </a>
```

Javascript:

```
    function read() {
        <%
            notificationDAO.read(((User)session.getAttribute("user")).getEmployeeID());
        %>
    }
```

Comment: A `select` element would be more semantic for drop-down UI and it also comes with an onchange event that you can hook into. I don't know if that will solve your problem but it will definitely clean things up a bit.

Comment: @RickViscomi I am using bootstrap drop-down and I wanted to find a solution to my problem without having to use `select` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing that you are using bootstrap the data-toggle has its own events

```
$('#myDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    call you read method here..
 })
```

Hope this helps.

https://jsbin.com/fayoda/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap data-toggle. However, the result is still the same. It is not working.

Comment: It actually worked. But including the 3 js/css files destroys the design of my web

Comment: you don't need to include those js files; as you are already using bootstrap and jquery. it should work with your bootstrap files.